Solutions to gradient flow
Consider the following gradient flow on a compact three-manifold. $$\partial_tA(t)=\star_3F(A(t)),$$ where $F$ is the curvature of the family of connections $A(t)$ taking values in some semisimple Lie-algebra. I believe a simple solution is $$A(t)=\frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)}A_{flat},$$ which connects the trivial connection $A=0$ and some flat connection. Are there some solution-generating techniques that produce trajectories which both start and end at non-trivial flat solutions? What Ansatz can I choose? I tried $A(t)=f(t)A_1+g(t)A_2$ for $A_1, A_2$ flat but I do not think that it is solvable without further assumptions. For the above solution I just used $A(t)=f(t)A_{flat}$. I also couldn't find any literature.
